# Monitoring multiple processes with same name

Tags: c#, wcf, process

I am working on a project where I started 4 processes using Process class and they have same name.

I tried using `Process.HasExited`, but because it's processes with same name, I can't really get one that is closed.

I also tried using ID, because they do have different ones, but it doesn't work how I thought it would, *e.g. when I close second process window and then check which ID is missing, he doesn't return that second ID is missing, it's always on random*.

I'm also using WCF connection, and I have `CheckState` method that all of my proxies are calling every five second, so when count of processes is less that 4 it return error and I know that one process is out.

This is how I start processes

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(path, Containers.Path.ports[i]);
                NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
                ChannelFactory<IContainer> factory = new ChannelFactory<IContainer>(binding, new EndpointAddress($"net.tcp://localhost:{Containers.Path.ports[i]}/IContainer")); 
                proxies.Add(factory.CreateChannel());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            }
        }
```

And this is how I check which process has stopped and I'm returning number from 0-3 because I have predefined "port" that I can use, so basically I just need to determine number of exited process

```
private static int GetID(Dictionary<int, int> processesIDs, Process[] newProcessList)
    {
        int cnt=0;
        int ret = -1;

        foreach (var p in processesIDs)
        {
            if(cnt == newProcessList.Length)
            {
                ret = p.Value;
                break;
            }else
            {
                cnt = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < newProcessList.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if (p.Key != newProcessList[i].Id)
                    {
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        if(ret == -1)
        {
            ret = 4;
        }else
        {
            ret = ret - 1;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

My assumption is that he doesn't line processes like I see it when console is running, meaning when I close second app window, I expect that second process is finished.

Comment: Please add code examples: how you create processes and how you check if they are still alive. Process ID is unique, so it is correct to use it for such task, but it is difficult to tell what you do wrong without code.

Comment: @IgorLabutin I edited post, I hope it helps

Comment: `Process.Start()` returns a `Process` - could you use those instead? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Just to explain, in this dictionary I stored processes IDs as Key and numbers from 0 to 3 as Values, so basically I did use those processes, I just didn't store them at beginning, I used  `Process.GetProcessesByName` function.

Comment: @Serlok but when you keep the `Process` instances, you could check their `HasExited` property, right? Might be worth a shot.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis tried that too, problem is that processes have same name, so every time I close app window (1 out of 4 given processes) `HasExited` property is always triggered on first process.

Comment: @Serlok so you're saying you have two instances of `Process`, that you've obtained while you created the processes, and when you close the _second_ process, the `HasExited` property of the _first_ property becomes `true`? I can't reproduce that, even though the processes have the same name.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I have 4 instances of `Process` that are initialized when I run my program. I just tried again what u suggested, now it doesn't always trigger the first one, now it goes random, e.g. when I close second, `HasExited` is triggered on third, when I close first, it is triggered on second etc...

Comment: `GetProcessesByName` does not guarantee any order of processes being returned. You can't rely on the fact that the first process you started will always be returned as first one. The only guaranteed way is to store the ID of the process that `Process.Start()` returns.

Comment: @IgorLabutin Thanks for feedback, I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Evenhuis said, I stored processes at start, when I'm creating them, and I stored then in `public static Dictionary<Process, string>`.

Later, when I want to check which one has exited, I simply use this method

```
public static string GetPort(Dictionary<Process, string> OriginalprocessesIDs)
    {
        string ret = "";
        foreach(var p in processesIDs)
        {
            if(p.Key.HasExited)
            {
                ret = p.Value;
                OriginalprocessesIDs.Remove(p.Key);
                return ret;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Because `hasExited` property stays true on this process, I need to remove it from dict. When I want to start new process, I need to make new `ChannelFactory` and to save it to dict as new process.

```
public static void StartSingleProcess(string port)
    {
        Process p = Process.Start(Containers.Path.location, port);
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        ChannelFactory<IContainer> factory = new ChannelFactory<IContainer>(binding, new EndpointAddress($"net.tcp://localhost:{port}/IContainer")); // moraju se cuvati proxiji zbog poziva metode load n puta 
        proxies.Add(factory.CreateChannel());
        OriginalprocessesIDs.Add(p, port);
    }
```